# React App as a Django App in a Docker Container - connection refused when trying to access APIs on localhost:8000 urls

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, django-rest-framework, dockerfile

hope you might have some guidance for me on this.

Right now I have a React app that is part of a Django app (for the sake of ease of passing auth login tokens), which is now containerised in a single Dockerfile. Everything works as intended when it is run as a Docker instance locally, but the Docker Image is having issues, despite the fact that the webpages are visible when the Image is deployed on server.

Specifically, when the Docker image is accessed, the home page renders as expected, but then a number of fetch requests which usually go to `localhost:8000/<path>/<to>/<url>` return the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/<path>/<to>/<url> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

On a colleague's suggestion, I have tried changing localhost:8000 to the public IP address of the server the Docker Image is hosted on (eg 172.XX.XX.XXX:8000) but when I rebuild the React app, these changes do not remain, and it defaults back to localhost. Here are my questions:

Is this something I change from within the React application itself? Do I need manually assign an IP address? (This seems unlikely to me)

Or is this something to do with either the Django port settings, or the Dockerfile itself?

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common
    RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip
    RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-distutils \
        python3-setuptools
        RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip --upgrade pip
    # ???
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERD 1

# copy file form local machine to container
COPY ./requirement.txt /requirement.txt

# install dependency
# RUN pip install -r /requirement.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirement.txt
# create app folder in container
RUN mkdir /app

# set default working dictionary
WORKDIR /app

# copy local app folder to container folder
COPY ./app /app

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

Multiple technologies, multiple failure points - thanks in advance!

Comment: If react app is part of django app and is rendered as django template, you can set the api url in react app to `/<url-path>` instead of `localhost:8000/<url-path>`

Comment: Can you elaborate _deployed on server_ and _locally_? Seems that you missed to pass the `-p` parameter ? `docker run -p 8000:8000` ?

Comment: Do you have the Django App running on port 8000, or is the Django App doing requests to 8000? 
If the latter, what is running on port 8000 then?

Comment: The Django app is running on port 8000. The default urls (i.e. with no prefix) serve the React files, which are a sub-app of the Django app. Other urls with prefixes like `/core/<parameters>` access the views in separate apps of the Django app. These urls are accessible and work when tested locally (= run in a docker container on development computer) but not when deployed as a docker image (= a docker image has been created and run)

Comment: You need to post the explicit command that you used to run your docker container. I too suspect that you may have ran the container with `-p 80:8000`, which will be a problem as when you access your webpage, your browser will be the thing sending follow-up requests and will be trying to access `8000` on your host machine incorrectly.